# Не могу получить значения this

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
var constants = {
    DIR: {
        HOME: "/",
        MODELS:  "/models",
        CONTROLLERS: "/controllers",
        ROUTES: "/routes",
        DATABASE: "/app/database",
        DATA: this.DIR
    },
    REQUIRE: {
        CONFIG: {
            DATABASE: 'config.json',
            APP: 'config.json'
        },
        UTILS: {
            HELPERS: {
                CRYPTO: 'utils/helpers/crypto.js'
            }
        }
    }
};

console.log(constants);
```

Вопрос почему  `DIR.DATA = undefined`? Каким образом обратится к внутренним переменным.?

Comment: DATA: constants.DIR

Comment: @Komdosh `Cannot read property 'DIR' of undefined"` это если использовать,что вы предлагаете

Answer (score 1):

В данном виде this == Window. this в метод засунуть нужно для привязки контекста. Тогда он будет ссылаться на внешний объект в момент вызова.
Получить DIR в его же методе (если так уж сильно хочется использовать контекст): `DATA: function () { return this }`

Answer (score 0):

```
const constants = {
DIR: {
    HOME: "/",
    MODELS:  "/models",
    CONTROLLERS: "/controllers",
    ROUTES: "/routes",
    DATABASE: "/app/database",
    get DATA() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

};

Либо просто методом.

Comment: будет `undefined`

Comment: Я не досмотрел. Там просто this.

Comment: Мы его вызываем как constants.DIR.DATA
Объект перед DATA - это DIR. Поэтому this - и так указывает непосредственно на него.